# Django form does not work or CSRF_token aborted

Tags: python, html, django

Hello I am making Django App. I have a problem with my login form. Whenever I want to login,
form does not do anything or it throws csrf token error.
Views:

```
def loginView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f"You successfully logged in {username}")
            return redirect('home-page')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'shop/login.html', {'form': form})
```

HTML TEMPLATE:

```
{% extends 'shop/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class = "form-container"> 
    <form class="form" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <label for="username">Email:</label>
        {{form.username}}
        <label for="password">Passoword:</label>
        {{form.password}}
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You do know about `django.contrib.auth`, right? It is the default handler of user auth in Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to check whether user existed or not in db if yes then login and redirect if not throw error or redirect on other page

```
def my_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('path')
            else:
                return redirect('path')
        else:
            return redirect('path')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
        return render(request, "shop/login.html", {'form': form})
```

still get error add the complete traceback & i will also suggest you to read the full documentation of django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/